# Micro-frontends react and flutter

Tags: reactjs, flutter, webpack, frontend, micro-frontend

I have multiple micro-frontends built in React. I want to create another micro-frontend with flutter and integrate with react app shell. Is it doable? Looking forward to your thoughts. Thanks